# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. Can't find the error in my code

Tags: javascript

So, first, I'm not done with my code.However, the following Javascript part is suppose to change the site language when an image is clicked. I read ( on other post here) that it could be because the whole html document has not finished loading? Anyway, here's my code: hope I can get some insight on what causes the error:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <title> Registration</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheetex3.css"/>
      <script>
             function changeLanguage()
            {
               document.getElementById("z").addEventListener("click");
               var Username1= document.getElementById("User");
               var Password1= document.getElementById("Pass");
               var Retype1= document.getElementById("Pass2");
               var Firstname1= document.getElementById("First");
               var Middlename1= document.getElementById("Second");
               var LastName1= document.getElementById("Third");
               var email1 = document.getElementById("at");
               var NomUtilisateur1 = document.createTextNode("Nom D'utilisateur");
               var mdp1 = document.createTextNode("Mot de Passe");
               var mdp21 = document.createTextNode("Verification du mot de passe");
               var Prenom1 = document.createTextNode("Prenom");
               var Prenom2 = document.createTextNode("Deuxieme prenom");
               var NomdeFamilly1 = document.createTextNode("Nom de Famille");
               var Email1 = document.createTextNode("Addresse courielle");
               Username1.appendChild(NomUtilisateur1);
               Password1.appendChild(mdp1);
               Retype1.appendChild(mdp21);
               Firstname1.appendChild(Prenom1);
               Middlename1.appendChild(Prenom2);
               LastName1.appendChild(NomdeFamilly1);
               email1.appendChild(Email1);
            }


        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    <div>
        <div>please fill out the form below</div>
        <div class="Img">
            <img id="z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR2pntKihP8gow1vBejsXhgYmHDctgwjcXKWKk9y0PEXsXEbUxpELQ" onClick="changeLanguage()" />
        </div>
        <form>
            <fieldset> 
                <legend id="login"> Login Details </legend>
                <p>Username* <input type="text" name="Username" id="User"></p>
                <p>Password* <input type="Password" name="Password" id="Pass"></input</p>
                <p>Retype Password*<input type="Password" name="RetypePassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" id="Pass2"></input></p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Data</legend>
                <p>Firstname* <input type="text" name="firstName"></input id="First"></p>
                <p>Middlename*<input type="text" name="middleName" id="Second"></input></p>
                <p>LastName*<input type="text"  name="lastName" id="Third"></input></p>
                <p>Email*<input type="email" name="email" id="at"> </input></p>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It simply means that one of your `getElementById()` calls is returning `null`, which means that the id you're looking for isn't in the document.

Comment: Also you cannot append child nodes to `<input>` elements.

Comment: Mhm, so I'd have to append it to p? (or table to make my page cleaner). However, that wouldn't erase my "old" writting. How can I make it disappear? or invisible maybe ? So i can switch between back and forth?

Comment: The title doesn't form your question, it's just a title. You should post a clear and concise question in the text of the question, preferably pointing out the line of code where it occurs. It would also help if you reduce your code to just sufficient to show the issue, not paste large slabs of irrelevant code and markup.

Comment: I've posted before snipplet and was called out for not showing enough. I don't like posting many line of the codes that are useless to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error in `<input type="text" name="firstName"></input id="First">`

Also, you can't append children to input element, instead you can insert them as its sibling

```js
function changeLanguage() {
  document.getElementById("z").addEventListener("click");
  var Username1 = document.getElementById("User");
  var Password1 = document.getElementById("Pass");
  var Retype1 = document.getElementById("Pass2");
  var Firstname1 = document.getElementById("First");
  var Middlename1 = document.getElementById("Second");
  var LastName1 = document.getElementById("Third");
  var email1 = document.getElementById("at");
  var NomUtilisateur1 = document.createTextNode("Nom D'utilisateur");
  var mdp1 = document.createTextNode("Mot de Passe");
  var mdp21 = document.createTextNode("Verification du mot de passe");
  var Prenom1 = document.createTextNode("Prenom");
  var Prenom2 = document.createTextNode("Deuxieme prenom");
  var NomdeFamilly1 = document.createTextNode("Nom de Famille");
  var Email1 = document.createTextNode("Addresse courielle");

  insertAfter(NomUtilisateur1, Username1);
  insertAfter(mdp1, Password1);
  insertAfter(mdp21, Retype1);
  insertAfter(Prenom1, Firstname1);
  insertAfter(Prenom2, Middlename1);
  insertAfter(NomdeFamilly1, LastName1);
  insertAfter(Email1, email1);
}

function insertAfter(node, anchor){
  if(anchor.nextSibling){
    anchor.parentNode.insertBefore(node, anchor.nextSibling);
  }else{
    anchor.parentNode.appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Registration Form</h1>

<div>
  <div>please fill out the form below</div>
  <div class="Img">
    <img id="z" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRR2pntKihP8gow1vBejsXhgYmHDctgwjcXKWKk9y0PEXsXEbUxpELQ" onClick="changeLanguage()" />
  </div>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="login">Login Details</legend>
      <p>Username*
        <input type="text" name="Username" id="User" />
      </p>
      <p>Password*
        <input type="Password" name="Password" id="Pass" />
      </p>
      <p>Retype Password*
        <input type="Password" name="RetypePassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" id="Pass2"/>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>User Data</legend>
      <p>Firstname*
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="First" />
      </p>
      <p>Middlename*
        <input type="text" name="middleName" id="Second" />
      </p>
      <p>LastName*
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="Third" />
      </p>
      <p>Email*
        <input type="email" name="email" id="at" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: Input element's don't have closing tags